# Is ATS implemented by default if the key is not present in Info.plist

Tags: ios, security, info.plist

According to Apple documentation, it says, "App Transport Security (ATS) is enabled by default for apps linked against the iOS 9.0 or macOS 10.11 SDKs or later, as indicated by the default Boolean value of NO for the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key."

For one of the applications, in Info.plist, **NSAppTransportSecurity** key itself is missing. My question is do we have to explicitly add:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

to enable ATS or it is enabled without explicitly declaring the above key.

Comment: It is enabled by default. I do not think you need to specifically put it in the plist

Comment: @shilpa We have to add `App Transport Security Settings` explicitly into info.plist file. Also we have to `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads ` to `YES`. By defaults it's value `NO`.

Comment: @PratikSodha By setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES, we are disabling ATS by allowing insecure connections.

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES - disables all ATS restrictions for all network connections, apart from the connections to domains that you configure individually in the optional NSExceptionDomains dictionary. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

Comment: I am aware of that. My question was, to enable App Transport Security for all network connections specific to an application, do we have to declare <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> in Info.plist or declaration is not required?

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks!